# Error al intentar conexion remota

Tags: mysql, android-studio, volley

Estoy intentando realizar un registro a la base de datos de **mysql** desde android.
a lo cual realice el código con **php**, comprobé que funcionara el código desde el navegador para después intentarlo desde la app movil.
a lo cual me manda el mensaje de error.

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

el código que utilizo para intentar el registro es el siguiente

```
private void cargarWebService() {
        progreso = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progreso.setMessage("Cargando...");
        progreso.show();
        String url = "http://192.168.0.55:8080/conexionremotaandroid/wsJSONRegistro.php?documento="+documento.getText().toString()+
                "&nombre="+nombre.getText().toString()+"&profesion="+profesion.getText().toString();


        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        progreso.hide();
        Toast.makeText(this,"No se pudo registrar"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Error: ",error.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Se ha registrado exitosamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        documento.setText("");
        nombre.setText("");
        profesion.setText("");

    }
```

Comment: ¿Si imprimes `url` y la pruebas en el navegador dices que funciona?  ¿Es un proceso largo el que ocurre en esa URL en el servidor?

Comment: agrega el metodo `trim()` =>`documento.getText().toString().trim()` igual como dic A.Cedano has un Log.i("tag**",url) para ver como va tu url)

Comment: He modificado el error que me sale, debido a que despues de investigar, no tenia habilitado el puerto 8080 que utilizo y probe que funcione desde el navegador del movil la url y funciona correctamente pero desde la app.. me mande el mensaje que muestro en la parte de arriba

Comment: te dice que no encuentra esa ulr, has un Toas o un Log para ver como se forma tu url, a lo mejor lleva espacios en blanco

Comment: hice un Log me manda lo siguiente  `I/Url->>: http://192.168.0.55:8080/conexionremotaandroid/wsJSONRegistro.php?documento=4&nombre=temp temp2&profesion=temp3` por lo tanto creo que si se crea un espacio, que solución le puedo dar?

Comment: el metodo trim()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He solucionado el problema agregado la siguiente linea de código

```
url = url.replace(" ","%20");
```

Ya que al ingresar nombres con espacios quedaba incompleto la **url**

quedando el código de la siguiente manera.

```
private void cargarWebService() {
        progreso = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progreso.setMessage("Cargando...");
        progreso.show();
        String url = "http://192.168.0.55:8080/conexionremotaandroid/wsJSONRegistro.php?documento="+documento.getText().toString()+
                "&nombre="+nombre.getText().toString()+"&profesion="+profesion.getText().toString();
        url = url.replace(" ","%20");


        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);

        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        Log.i("Url->>",url.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        progreso.hide();
        Toast.makeText(this,"No se pudo registrar"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Error: ",error.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        progreso.hide();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Se ha registrado exitosamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        documento.setText("");
        nombre.setText("");
        profesion.setText("");

    }
```